# How to send E Mail notification when a new Blog or Blog comment added in Alfresco 4.X?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am new bee to Alfresco. I just want to send an email alert to all site members when a new Blog or Blog comment added. Is that possible with Alfresco community 4.X??? Is any way to achieve this functionality ??

Thanks,
Prabhakar Manthena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by rules and by using the mail action.

The rule can be set through the Repository viewer on e.g.:company home/sites/swsdp/blog
The first one is to set on incoming content and the second one is a bit harder.

There is a **fm:commentCount** which gets updated and you can check on that one on a change rule. This can be done by a behaviour to check if the property has been changed or you can go through the object and locate if a new comment has been added (check by date for example)